# Pass variable from jenkins pipeline job to other pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

Pass variable from jenkins pipeline job to other pipeline job:

I have a following job:

```
stage ('Upgrade') {

  steps {

    build job: 'Upgrade', 
        parameters: [string(name: 'sourcePath', value: '%publishPath%"\"%folderBuild%')]

         }

      }
```

Call to other job

```
pipeline {

 agent { label 'master' }

 stages {
   stage('Upgrade') {

     steps {
       sh "ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml --extra-vars "name=build_path value=%sourcePath%"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

**Question: what's wrong?**

Comment: There is no direct way where the var defined in one job can be used by another job. You have to explicitly call the other job and pass the value. Post Build action is one such way

Answer (score 0):

---

stage ('Upgrade') {

steps {

build job: 'Upgrade', parameters: [string(name: 'sourcePath', value: env.buildPath)]

}

}

---

In following this job you have to define String parameter called SourcePath

stages {

stage('Upgrade') {

steps {
     sh label: '', script: 'ansible-playbook -i inventory upgrade.yml -e "buildPath=${sourcePath}"'

}

}

}

---

In Ansible create env var as following:

vars:

build_path: "{{ buildPath }}"   // buildPath from Jenkins job